# Display of data after using scrolling mouse

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to do in JavaFX getting of the TableView from the database, but I have a lot of records it needs to load in small portions (eg. 50 position), and that it gets the remaining little by little as I scroll the scroll wheel. Any tips? or where can I find some good example?

Comment: You could try to check if the scrollbar is at the bottom, if it's true then you just have to add more elements to the `TableView` and repeat the process until you have no elements left.

Comment: I have found [this example](http://www.superglobals.net/javafx-listview-lazy-loading/).
It uses a `ListView` but the process is the same.

Comment: ok, thanks. You can add as a response

Comment: If you give me some time I can write an example using the TableView

Comment: ok, i will be wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example I'll use a Person class that represent an element in the table.

```
public class Person {

    private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");

    private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        setFirsName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
    }

    public void setFirsName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

}
```

Here the Main class:

```
public class TableViewOnScroll extends Application {

    private ObservableList<Person> peopleToAdd;

    private int start = 0;
    private int step = 50;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<Person>();

        ObservableList<Person> displayedPeople = getInitialPeople();
        peopleToAdd = getPeopleToAdd();

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        TableColumn<Person,String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

        tableView.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        tableView.setItems(displayedPeople);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

        // Be sure to put the listener after the stage is shown or the application will throw a NullPointerException
        ScrollBar tableViewScrollBar = getTableViewScrollBar(tableView);
        tableViewScrollBar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                double position = newValue.doubleValue();
                ScrollBar scrollbar = getTableViewScrollBar(tableView);
                if(position == scrollbar.getMax()) {
                    if(step <= peopleToAdd.size()) {
                        displayedPeople.addAll(peopleToAdd.subList(start, step));
                        start = step;
                        step += 50;
                        tableView.scrollTo(start);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPeopleToAdd() {
        ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            people.add(new Person("Patty", "Johnson"));
        }

        return people;
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getInitialPeople() {
        ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            people.add(new Person("John", "Smith"));
        }

        return people;
    }

    private ScrollBar getTableViewScrollBar(TableView<?> listView) {
        ScrollBar scrollbar = null;
        for (Node node : listView.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
                ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) node;
                if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
                    scrollbar = bar;
                }
            }
        }
        return scrollbar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The use of the getInitialPeople() and getPeopleToAdd() is only to populate the lists with some random data.

Comment: Ok, if you have problems or questions about the code I posted, I will be glad to help you.